# ReactJs: Displaying the values inside of a state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, foreach, javascript-objects

I am trying to display the values inside a state object:
I have tried two methods:

> Method 1:

```
 <tbody>
                    {Object.keys(this.state.operationSavInformation).map(
                      function(key, index) {
                        return (
                          <tr key={key}>
                            <td>{`${key}:`}</td>
                            <td>
                              <strong>
                                {this.state.operationSavInformation[key]}
                              </strong>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        );
                      }
                    )}
                  </tbody>
```

> Method 2:

```
<tbody>
                {Object.keys(this.state.operationSavInformation).forEach(
                  function(key) {
                    var value = this.state.operationSavInformation[key];
                    return (
                      <tr key={key}>
                        <td>{`${key}:`}</td>
                        <td>
                          <strong>value</strong>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  }
                )}
              </tbody>
```

Both give this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Unfortunately, these are the only two ways I've found to **map over** an object values in javaScript. This would work if the object was defined normally. However the problem here is that **this** is not accessible inside `map` or `forEach`, that's why I get the error.

Comment: Wait, I misread your code. What you need is `<tbody>{Object.entries(this.state.operationSavInformation).map(([key, value]) => ...)}</tbody>` Anyway, if you use an arrow function instead, you can still access the outer `this`.

Comment: Here's a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dubinsky-tkw6o

Comment: seems, your code is correct.
I think the error is that you write this code not in react component.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much, that solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

Just grab a reference to it outside the predicate function, like this:

```
const data = this.state.operationSavInformation
Object.keys(data).map(key => (<tr key={key}>
  <td>{`${key}:`}</td>
  <td>
    <strong>
      {data[key]}
    </strong>
  </td>
</tr>
))
```

Comment: You can't do that inside JSX

Comment: Can you not grab the reference at the start of the render function and then the Object.keys is in your return statement?

Comment: That's definitely how you do it. It's the old `const that = this` workaround. You just need to figure out where to put it in the syntax.

Comment: You shouldn't need it here if you use an arrow function. OP is using `function` which shadowed the instance `this`.

Comment: I have solved my problem though. Check out the answers in the comments

Comment: I've rewritten my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dubinsky-tkw6o) to use this method, which of course works just fine. An answer should be a little more precise with the syntax though and include where each line goes in the context of the render function.

Comment: Came back to add a note about the arrow function. Glad you fixed it!